# Newspaper sentence translation and interpretation

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, verbs, newspaper-grammar

I would like to know if my translation of the sentence below is accurate in meaning. If not, could you point out the problematic area? Simply pointing out where I went wrong would be great. No need to explain, I’ll do the research on my own.

#### ⓐ安倍総理大臣は、ⓑ宣言を続ける所は「ウイルスがうつる人は少なくなって、ⓒ病院でしっかり治療できるようになって、ⓓ前よりよくなっている」と言っています。

#### “Prime Minister Abe is saying in his declaration that about the places which continue the emergency measures, the infected people are decreasing and at the hospitals a cure has reached a point where it’s becoming possible before the infected becoming better”

ⓐ安倍総理大臣は

Note:
So the idea here is that at the very end you have the quotation particle と followed by 言っています. This is because the article is quoting 安倍総理大臣. The quote begins in ⓑ and ends in ⓓ.

Prime minister Shinzo Abe is the topic of the sentence

ⓑ宣言を続ける所は「ウイルスがうつる人は少なくなって、

Re: 宣言【せんげん】:

We might note that it is the 宣言i.e. declaration/announcement[…]
… so the declaration is the direct object of the と言っています at the very end in the sense of: “The prime minister has said in an announcement”.

I hesitated about 続ける所 until I realised he (Shinzo) is probably talking about the places that continue with the emergency measures in the previous :

Tokyo metropolitan area, Saitama prefecture, Chiba prefecture, Kanagawa prefecture and Hokkaido island

(The quote I mentioned before begins here).

ウイルス『が』

The virus is the subject of the sentence…

うつる人『は』

I looked up うつる 【移る】on Weblio and settled with this definition:

ⓔ to be infected, to be contagious, to spread (as in fire)
…as it said it was generally written in kana alone.
少なくなって

Is actually a whole verb! 少なくなる which means:

ⓐ to lessen, to decrease, to diminish
“The people infected by the virus are decreasing…”

ⓒ病院でしっかり治療できるようになって

病院『で』

… the hospital(s) + 『place of action』

しっかり

is brand new to me:

ⓐ tightly (holding on), firmly, securely
治療

means “a cure”.

ようになる

is an expression:

ⓐ to reach the point that, to come to be that, to turn into
“At the hospitals, we are reaching a point where a reliable (しっかり) cure is becoming possible”

ⓓ前よりよくなっている」と言っています。
The part following the 」is “saying that”.

I think this last part says that the うつる人 will need the cure mentioned in the previous part before (前) they become better (よりよくなっている).

### Source:

https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012440031000/k10012440031000.html